# Show Document Icon in a SPGridView

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, document-library, caml-query

I'm using SharePoint 2013 foundation.I have created a CAML query to get fields. I capture the results coming from the CAML query in a SPListItemCollection and then bind to a SPGridView.

```
<FieldRef Name='DocIcon'/>
<FieldRef Name='ServerUrl'/>
<FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef'/> 
<FieldRef Name='GUID'/>
```

The DocIcon gives 'docx' and ServerUrl gives the path to the doc '/sub1/Shared Documents/Document 1.docx'.

Is there any field that could be used to display the document icon ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get the document icon as a property, you will have to make the url for it.

SharePoint has already lots of icons available in the DOCICON.xml file at C:/Program Files/Common Files/Microsoft Shared/web server extensions/14/TEMPLATE/XML

Simplest way could be to load based on file extension "/_layouts/images/icXXX.gif (where icXXX, would be icdoc.gif, idpdf.gif, etc.)

You will have to take the file extension by splitting by the last '.' sign and create the url using code or a regular expression.

Reference: [Answer by C.Marius](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/78358/how-to-get-file-or-list-item-icon-in-sharepoint-2013-using-javascript)